# Replacing value in SAS

Tags: sas

I have some variables having values `-980, -987, -995`.

Dataset

```
fact_1   fact_2   fact_3   fact_4 
 0        -980     -21      -995    
 12         0      -987     -214   
 24        12      43       -124   
...
```

I would like to replace with a missing value where var has values listed above: `-980, -987, -995`.

Expected output:

```
fact_1   fact_2   fact_3   fact_4 
 0          .    -21         .      
 12         0      .        -214    
 24        12      43       -124   
...
```

Can you please tell me how to do it in SAS? I would use replace in Python but I actually I do not know how to check if a variable has a specified value to change in SAS.

Comment: Do the values -980, -987 and -995 have special meaning?  If so perhaps you should change each value to a different special missing value instead of collapsing them all into the same missing value. For example -980 to .A and -987 to .B and -995 to .C.

Answer (score 2):

The way to change the value of a variable in SAS is to use an assignment statement.

```
fact_4 = .;
```

The way to test if a variable has a specific value is to test for equality with `=`. To conditionally execute a statement use the IF/THEN structure.

```
if fact_4 = -980 then fact_4 = .;
```

To test if a variable is any of a list of values use the `IN` operator instead.

```
if fact_4 in (-980 -987 -995) then fact_4 = .;
```

Note that those statements work in a DATA step. So if your existing dataset is named HAVE you should run a data step to create a new dataset named WANT that has the values changed.

So your full program might look like:

```
data want;
  set have;
  if fact_1 in (-980 -987 -995) then fact_1 = .;
  if fact_2 in (-980 -987 -995) then fact_2 = .;
  if fact_3 in (-980 -987 -995) then fact_3 = .;
  if fact_4 in (-980 -987 -995) then fact_4 = .;
run;
```

If you have a lot of similar variables then you probably will want to use an ARRAY rather than creating wallpaper code.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array fix3 fact_1-fact_4;
  do index=1 to dim(fix3 );
    if fix3[index] in (-980 -987 -995) then fix3[index]= .;
  end;
  drop index;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. However I was wondering if it would be possible to do it automatically. I have many factors (around 100). I started to do as you shown but I stopped at fact_20. Do you know if this is something that can be automated? I was thinking of a do over the columns and see per each of them if contains one of the values that I want to replace

Comment: Learn about ARRAY and variable lists.

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` operator can work with literal lists of values as shown by @Tom and also with arrays!

Example:

Loop over the values to be tested, which have been arrayed, testing each against the arrayed list of values to be converted to missing.

```
data have;
  do rownum = 1 to 100;
    array x x1-x100;
    do _n_ = 1 to 100;
      x(_n_) = rownum - 100 - _n_;
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  array nullify (6) _temporary_ (-99, -77, -69, -96, -25, -42);

  set have;

  array values x1-x100;

  do _n_ = 1 to dim(values);
    if values(_n_) in nullify then call missing(values(_n_));
  end;
run;
```